# How to animate the start position object on the wave modifier?

Tags: animation, modifiers

So I have a scene where my object has the wave modifier and the start position object is an empty axis. Here's my wave modifier settings:

[image: settings]

Here's what happens when drag the empty nearby:

[image: effect]

but when the empty is animated as soon as it gets nearby, nothing happens:

[image: no effect]

Also if it helps I have a subdivision modifier above the wave one.

Do I have to apply the wave modifier? Is there something obvious I'm missing? Or can you simply not animate the start position object?

Thanks!

Comment: Continued this question over here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39301/how-to-make-a-wave-that-follows-empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproducing what you have described and it seems to work fine.
Upon opening the file, press Alt+A to test the animation and try moving the non animated empty to see.

[image]

We can investigate more what is causing this but you shouldn't need to apply the modifier. In fact, applying it will remove the interaction between the empty and the mesh and just turn the sphere to the shape it is under the influence permanently.

Providing more details about how did you animate the empty would also help.

Comment: I tried your settings on my .blend and now it works, but it doesn't create my previous effect. I'll try to find out which of the settings are messing it up

Comment: turns out it waves only seem to happen when the lifetime is at zero.I'll follow up another question asking about how to animate the effect I'm trying to make