# How to make a wave that follows empty?

Tags: modifiers

So I'm trying to make it so that when the empty goes across the object it creates a wave. I'm following up [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39294/how-to-animate-the-start-position-object-on-the-wave-modifier/39299#39299) question. Here's the .blend

[image]

As you can see if you drag the empty slowly across the object it creates a single wave but if you play the animation it just makes multiple waves. I'm trying to re-create the effect you get from dragging the empty across the object. How would you do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make just one wave uncheck the Cyclic option on the wave modifier.

Then just find the proper offset so that when the empty moves across the object the wave occurs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

Another option I can think of (not knowing what you are after ultimately) is not using a wave modifier but a displace modifier, and using the empty to control the texture. Animating the strenght as the empty goes across the sphere can give a nice result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I guess there isn't a way in achieving the exact effect but the displace one is pretty good